# proving null set for Sphere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I’m stuck at the following question, and I would love if someone can maybe help me crack this:

**the Question:**

let $S_{R}^{n -1}\subseteq R^n$ be a sphere of Radius $R$

$S_{R}^{n -1}=\left\{ x\in R^n : ||x||=R\right\}$

prove $S_{R}^{n -1}$ is a null set

**definition**:

null set:
we will call A null set, if for every $\varepsilon $>0 there exist a series of open\closed cubes $ \left\{Q_j \right\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ that cover A ($A\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}Q_j$) and also $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}Vol(Q_j)<\varepsilon  $

I dont understand how Im supposed to "build" cubes so I cover the sphere, those are still the very first questions I do in this subject, so I hoped someone can explain to me how to plan the solution please

Comment: One good strategy for a problem like this is to try the simplest case first, and look for a pattern that you can generalize. Have you tried the case $n=2$?

Comment: @roy Are you aware of [diffeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism)?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Im not familiar with diffeomorphism, I only learned the definition above, and I have proved before that Graph of funciton is null set

Comment: You can apply this result about graph of functions to this case by taking a subset of the sphere.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net hi, sorry but Im still having touble understanding how to do it, how do I know what subset to take? how does looking at a subset will allow me to use the result of graph of function?

Comment: Take any subset $s$ of the sphere such that the complete sphere can included in a finite union $1 \le I \le m$ of $T_i (s)$ where $T_i$ is an isometric transformation.

Comment: Taking @LeeMosher's suggestion of considering the case $n = 2$, you might imagine displaying a circle on a pixellated display. Suppose you tried to draw a one-inch radius circle with half-inch pixels, how many pixels would you need, and how much total area would they cover? How about with quarter-inch pixels? Tenth-inch pixels? Hundredth-inch pixels? Does that suggest that you can get the total area to be as small as desired? Then see if you can generalize to larger $n$.

Answer (score 2):

For $r > 0$, let $B_r = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| < r\}$. Let $h > 0$. We have
$$m(S^{n - 1}_r) \leq m(B_{r + h} \setminus B_{r - h}) = m(B_{r + h}) - m(B_{r - h}) = (r + h)^nm(B_1) - (r - h)^nm(B_1).$$
Now let $h \to 0$ to get
$$m(S^{n - 1}_r) \leq \lim_{h \to 0}((r + h)^nm(B_1) - (r - h)^nm(B_1)) = 0.$$

Comment: Hi, sorry for asking, but its just Im really new to this, and we havent learned some of the things you wrote here:
what does B represent?
why can you look at the result as h approch 0 and conculde from that about the measurement?

Comment: @roy I wrote out more details.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & \mathbb D^{n-1} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & (x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) & \longmapsto & \sqrt{1 - x_1^2 - \dots - x_{n-1}^2} \end{array}$$ where $\mathbb D^{n-1} = \{(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) \mid x_1^2 + \dots + x_{n-1}^2 \le 1\}$

Then $s=G(f) = \{(x, f(x)) \mid x \in \mathbb D^{n-1}\}$ is the graph of $f$ and can be identified to a half of the sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb R^n$.

Hence using the result that you know about the null measure of the graph of a function, you can conclude that $s$ is a null set of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and therefore $\mathbb S^{n-1}$.